# Rally project scope down does not cover all projects

Tags: rally

I have about 400 child projects under a certain project. When I create a data store getting filtered stories from this project and set projectScopeDown = true & projectScopeUp = false, the results returned are not from all the sub projects. Some projects are left out. Is there any solution to this?  I am using Rally SDk version 2.0rc2

Here is my entire code (Note that the limit: 5000 is not playing a role here because the results returned are well below the limit).

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
items:[{ xtype: 'container', itemId: 'print_button_box', padding: 5},{xtype: 'container', itemId: 'grid_box'}],
count: 0,
globalStore: null,
totalDataLength: 0,
gridCounter: 0,
launch: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.globalStore = null;
    this.gridCounter = 0;
    this.totalDataLength=0;
    this.count = 0;
    this._addPrintButton();
     list = [];
    //Write app code here
    var prefix_set = ["Epic:","Arch:","Refa:","Innov:","Spike:","Producer:","Dependency:","Consumer:"];
    var i;
    Ext.getBody().mask('Preparing Table...');
     Deft.Promise.all([
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Spike:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Epic:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Refa:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Producer:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Consumer:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Innov:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Dependency:"),
    this._get_stories_of_feature("Arch:")
]).then({
    success: function(recordSets) {
        console.log("Total Data Length ",me.totalDataLength);

        console.log("Building store");
                //once all the stories and feature data is computed
                var myStore = Ext.create("Rally.data.custom.Store",{
                data: list,
                sortable: true,
                pageSize: me.totalDataLength,

            });
            Ext.getBody().unmask();
            me._showGrid(myStore); 
    },
    failure: function() {
        //Handle error loading the store here...
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
        me.hideMask();
        console.log("Error handling");

    }
});


},
_addPrintButton: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.down('#print_button_box').add( { 
        xtype: 'rallybutton', 
        itemId: 'print_button',
        text: 'CSV',
        disabled: false,
        handler: function() {
           console.log('globalStore ',me.globalStore);
            me.exportGrid(me.globalStore);
        }
    });
},
_onClickExport: function () {

     if (document.getElementById('grid_box')) {

        //Ext.getBody().mask('Exporting Tasks...');
        console.log('inside export');
        setTimeout(function () {
            var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-' +
                'microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>' +
                '<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>' +
                '{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
                '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}' +
                '</table></body></html>';

            var base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            };
            var format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };
            var table = document.getElementById('grid_box');
            console.log("Exporting table ",table);
            var excel_data = '<tr>';
            Ext.Array.each(table.innerHTML.match(/<span .*?x-column-header-text.*?>.*?<\/span>/gm), function (column_header_span) {
                excel_data += (column_header_span.replace(/span/g, 'td'));
            });
            excel_data += '</tr>';
            Ext.Array.each(table.innerHTML.match(/<tr class="x-grid-row.*?<\/tr>/gm), function (line) {
                excel_data += line.replace(/[^\011\012\015\040-\177]/g, '>>');
            });
            console.log("Excel data ",excel_data);
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: excel_data};
            window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64(format(template, ctx));
            Ext.getBody().unmask();
        }, 500);
    }else{
        console.log("grid_box does not exist");
    }
},
tableToExcel: function(){
    var me = this;
    console.log("Global store ",me.globalStore);
     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }); };

     return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML};
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  };
},

_showGrid: function(store){
    var me = this;
    if(!this.grid){
        this.grid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid',{
            store: store,
            columnCfgs:[
                {text: 'Feature', dataIndex: 'name'},
                {text: 'FormattedID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID'},
                {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'UserStories'},
                {text: 'Release', dataIndex: 'Release'},
                {text: 'Iteration', dataIndex: 'Iteration'},
                {text: 'DIteration', dataIndex: 'DIteration'},
                {text: 'DPSI', dataIndex: 'DPSI'},
                {text: 'Schedule State', dataIndex: 'ScheduleState'},
                {text: 'Task Remaining Total', dataIndex: 'TaskRemainingTotal'},
                {text: 'Owner', dataIndex: 'Owner'},,
                {text: 'Project', dataIndex: 'Project'},
                {text: 'Not fully Planned', dataIndex: 'Unscheduled'}
            ]
        });
        me.globalStore = this.grid;
        this.grid.store.sort([
            {property: 'DDR', dataIndex: 'DDR'}
        ]);
        this.down('#grid_box').add(this.grid);
    }
},
_get_stories_of_feature: function(name){
    var me = this;
    var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
        autoLoad: true,
        model: "HierarchicalRequirement",
        limit: Infinity,
        fetch: ['Name','ObjectID','FormattedID','Parent','Feature','TaskRemainingTotal','c_DIteration','c_DPSI','DragAndDropRank','Release','Iteration','Project','Owner','ScheduleState'],
        sorters:[{
            property: 'DragAndDropRank', direction: 'ASC'
        }],
        filters:[{
            property: 'Name', operator: 'contains', value: name
        },{
            property: 'ScheduleState', operator: '!=', value: 'Accepted'
        }],
        context:{
            projectScopeDown: true,
            projectScopeUp: false
        },

        pageSize: 5000,
        listeners:{
            load: function(store,data,success){
                if(success==true){
                    console.log(success);
                    me.totalDataLength+=data.length;
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        var flag; var iteration ="";
                        var release = ""; var fid="",fname="";
                        var owner = "";


                        if(data[i].data.Feature!=null && (data[i].data.Feature.c_DIteration==null || data[i].data.Feature.c_DIteration.toString().indexOf("*")!=-1))
                             flag = "YES";
                        else flag = "NO";

                        if(data[i].data.Iteration!=null){
                            iteration = data[i].data.Iteration._refObjectName;
                        }
                        if(data[i].data.Release!=null){
                            release = data[i].data.Release._refObjectName;
                        }
                        if(data[i].data.Owner!=null){
                            owner = data[i].data.Owner._refObjectName;
                        }
                        if(data[i].data.Feature!=null){
                            fid = data[i].data.Feature.FormattedID;
                            fname = data[i].data.Feature.Name; 
                        }
                        var element = {
                            name: fid!="" ? fid+":"+fname : "",
                            UserStories: data[i].data.Name,
                            Project: data[i].data.Project._refObjectName,
                            Owner: owner,
                            FormattedID: data[i].data.FormattedID,
                            Iteration: iteration,
                            DDR: data[i].data.DragAndDropRank,
                            TaskRemainingTotal: parseInt(data[i].data.TaskRemainingTotal),
                            Release: release,
                            ScheduleState: data[i].data.ScheduleState,
                            DIteration: data[i].data.c_DIteration,
                            DPSI: data[i].data.c_DPSI,
                            Unscheduled: flag                                   
                        };
                        list.push(element);
                        console.log("Pushed to list");
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }else{
                    console.log(success);
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            }

        }
        });
    console.log("Returning deferred");
    return deferred.promise;


},
 exportGrid: function(grid) {
    if (Ext.isIE) {
        this._ieToExcel(grid);

    } else {
        var data = this._getCSV(grid);

        window.location = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    }
},

_escapeForCSV: function(string) {
    if (string.match(/,/)) {
        if (!string.match(/"/)) {
            string = '"' + string + '"';
        } else {
            string = string.replace(/,/g, ''); // comma's and quotes-- sorry, just loose the commas
        }
    }
    return string;
},

_getFieldText: function(fieldData) {
    var text;

    if (fieldData == null || fieldData == undefined) {
        text = '';

    } else if (fieldData._refObjectName && !fieldData.getMonth) {
        text = fieldData._refObjectName;

    } else if (fieldData instanceof Date) {
        text = Ext.Date.format(fieldData, this.dateFormat);

    } else if (!fieldData.match) { // not a string or object we recognize...bank it out
        text = '';

    } else {
        text = fieldData;
    }

    return text;
},

_getFieldTextAndEscape: function(fieldData) {
    var string  = this._getFieldText(fieldData);

    return this._escapeForCSV(string);
},

_getCSV: function (grid) {
    var cols    = grid.columns;
    var store   = grid.store;
    var data    = '';
console.log("Grid.Store is ",grid.store);
    var that = this;
    Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
        if (col.hidden != true) {
            data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(col.text) + ',';
        }
    });
    data += "\n";

    store.each(function(record) {
        var entry       = record.getData();
        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                var text        = entry[fieldName];

                data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(text) + ',';
            }
        });
        data += "\n";
    });

    return data;
},

_ieGetGridData : function(grid, sheet) {
    var that            = this;
    var resourceItems   = grid.store.data.items;
    var cols            = grid.columns;

    Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
        if (col.hidden != true) {
            console.log('header: ', col.text);
            sheet.cells(1,colIndex + 1).value = col.text;
        }
    });

    var rowIndex = 2;
    grid.store.each(function(record) {
        var entry   = record.getData();

        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                var text        = entry[fieldName];
                var value       = that._getFieldText(text);

                sheet.cells(rowIndex, colIndex+1).value = value;
            }
        });
        rowIndex++;
    });
},

_ieToExcel: function (grid) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        var  xlApp, xlBook;
        try {
            xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
        } catch (e) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'For the export to work in IE, you have to enable a security setting called "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe" from Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level..."');
            return;
        }

        xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate;
        var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet;
        xlApp.visible = true; 

       this._ieGetGridData(grid, XlSheet);
       XlSheet.columns.autofit; 
    }
},
showMask: function(msg) {
    if ( this.getEl() ) { 
        this.getEl().unmask();
        this.getEl().mask(msg);

    }
},
hideMask: function() {
    this.getEl().unmask();
}



});
```

Comment: If you remove the hard coded context and set the app context manually in Rally, do you see the same result? You might also try explicitly adding the project ID to the context; I'm not sure it's set by default.

Comment: I tried to set the app context manually, doesn't get all.

Comment: If you can identify a project it's Not returning results for, what happens if you set that project in the context?  (Looking to see if it's a permissions issue.)